# Запись в куки

Tags: php, cookie

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы куки записывались с первого раза?

У меня есть файл header.php и index.php в header.php идёт запись в куки

```
if(!empty($_GET["id"])){
   $id = (int)$_GET["id"];
   setCookie("id_shop", $id);
}
```

А в файле индекс вывод данных

```
Вы вошли в магазин: <?php echo $_COOKIE["id_shop"]; ?>
```

Так вот в чём проблема, чтобы страница index.php вывела id нужно с этим id страницу загрузить 2 раза. Т.е вы перешли site.ru/?id=1 и теперь по этому-же адресу надо перейти ещё раз чтобы данные сохранились. Помогите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы вот зашёл на страницу под site.ru/?id=1 и сразу же на index.php выводился этот id(именно из куков)

Comment: Но ведь, я до этого подключил файл header.php где всё записывается...

Comment: $_COOKIE это массив который получает сервер, функция setCookie() не меняет его. http://ideone.com/n1MtxT#view_edit_box

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло! А скажите а почему это не по правилам? Работает-же...

Comment: не по правилам, потому, что в этой переменной мы ожидаем то что пришло от сервера.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А откуда кука возьмется, если её ещё не задали ? в смысле вы можете конечно дополнительно еще и в массив $_COOKIE свою куку записать, но это не по правилам.

```
if(!empty($_GET["id"])){
   $id = (int)$_GET["id"];
   setCookie("id_shop", $id);
   $_COOKIE["id_shop"]=$id;
}
```